# Different outputs while printing the WebElements in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've initialized all the WebElements in the project using PageFactory. For logging purpose I am trimming the logs of the elements. But I faced some difficulty while trimming. So when I tried to print the elements, I found that most of the times an element is printed in this manner:
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (d96cf99661f5d938b75f8448dad62d3b)] -> xpath: //button[@ng-reflect-label='Add']]

but in extremely minor cases, it is printed this way:
Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //div[contains(@class,'ui-growl-icon-close')]'

My trimming method looks for "->" in the element so most of the times it works, but rarely it fails when it changes to "Proxy element for..." 
Thing is there is no consistency in the elements when they get printed. Element getting printed as "Proxy element for..." would get printed as "[[ChromeDriver.." in the next iteration

Browser used: chrome (only)

Comment: Update the question with your _code trials_ please.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `PageFactory` for initializing `webelement` it initializes it with a `Proxy` object. Only when you access the element from your code, like a sendkeys, is the actual `webelement` retrieved and initialized fully.

For a code level discussion of how selenium pagefactory initializes refer to this. http://www.alechenninger.com/2014/07/a-case-study-of-javas-dynamic-proxies_14.html